# Angular: setting height of body/html based on presence of component

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am using Angular 5.0.5 My app has several pages configured via RouterModule (@angular/router)

I a using flex layout. body/html tags has some min height and using flex layout defined positioning of elements. If a component or an element inside component needs more space, it would scroll within component. Whole document scroll would happen only when browser is resized below min-height of body/html.

Now I don't want fixed min-height for body/html. I want to change it if particular url/component is loaded. I have explored :host selectors as well. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think your question is not related to angular at all. This is a question about css. Angular doesn't provide any extra functionality for this.

Comment: it is related to angular because I want styling based on presence of "Angular Component". Pure css doesn't know anything about angular components! Whether angular provides extra functionality for this or not is different questions, That is why I asked this to know.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't this the default behaviour of `overflow-y: auto` ?

Comment: yes, but instead of whole page scroll, I wanted to have scoll on particular container wherever needed.

Comment: so then you would do this: :host { display: block; height: 200px; overflow: auto; }. and everything inside the component outside the 200 px would be reachable via scrolling in this component

Comment: :host styles host element, not ancestor. One hack I thought was to access native document.body and adding removing classes from component on ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy